# Legit python if statement?

Tags: python

I am new to Python and trying to build a practice project that reads some XML.  For some reason this if statement is triggered even for blank whitespace lines:

```
if '<' and '>' in line:
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Why did you write this statement?  Where have you seen code like this?  What do you think this is supposed to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code says (parethesised for clarity):

```
if '<' and ('>' in line):
```

Which evaluates to:

```
if True and ('>' in line):
```

Which in your case evaluates to `true` when you don't intend to. So, try this instead (parenthesis are optional, but added for clarity):

```
if ('<' in line) and ('>' in line):
```

Comment: How is `if true and ('>' in line):` always true? I could see it if it used `or`.

Comment: Did you actually try typing any of that in at the interactive prompt? The relative precedence of `in` and `and` is correct in this case without parentheses and `True in ''` doesn't always return `True`, it raises `TypeError`.

Comment: @ncoghlan: Yes, actually (PS, I fixed the parens again). The interesting question is, why would it evaluate to True on an empty line according to the OP?

Comment: "correct" is the wrong word (since the expression doesn't correctly the OP's intentions), but the relative precedence of the two operators is as described in your original (pre-edit) answer and in payne's current answer.

Comment: See my answer - something else is going on if the OP is seeing that condition trigger on apparently empty lines (my guess is stale data in `line`, but we don't really have enough info at this point). I removed the downvote now that you corrected the parens :)

Answer (score 9):

You probably want:

```
if ('<' in line) and ('>' in line):
```

Your version is being interpreted as this:

```
if ('<') and ('>' in line):
```

which is probably not what you meant.

**Use parenthesis to make things super-obvious.**

Comment: This is accurate, but doesn't explain the OP's problem (i.e. if `line == ''` the OP's expression should still return `False` despite their error).

Answer (score 3):

How certain are you that `line` is genuinely empty when you hit a blank line in the file?

When you write `'<' and '>' in line` the interpreter sees that as `'<' and ('>' in line)` which isn't what you want: you're after something more like `'<' in line and '>' in line` or `all(x in line for x in '<>')`. None of those expressions, including your original, will be true when `line` is empty, though. The incorrect form of the expression *will* however, give an incorrect answer when the string contains only `'>'`.

```
>>> '<' and '>' in ''
False
>>> '<' and '>' in '<'
False
>>> '<' and '>' in '>' # Huh?
True
>>> 1 and 0 in [0]  # Perhaps this will clarify matters
True
```

Regardless, don't parse XML by hand - use an XML parsing library, such as the `xml.etree.ElementTree` module included in the standard library.

Answer (score 2):

Try:
`if '<' in line and '>' in line:`

I'd suggest reading a book on Python before diving in, you'll avoid *a lot* of pitfalls :)